Prove that if $f$ is continuous, and has two asymptotes, then it is uniformly continuous (Argument check)
The exercise is the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ continuous such that
$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f(x) = \ell_1$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} f(x) = \ell_2$ for some certain $\ell_1,\ell_2 \in \mathbb{R}$
Prove that f is uniformly continuous.

This is my attempt:
I know, by hypothesis that 
$\exists M_1 > 0 / x>M_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-\ell_1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ 
$\exists M_2 > 0 / x<-M_2 \Rightarrow |f(x)-\ell_2|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$
Let $M:=\max\{M_1,M_2\}$
I "divide" the proof into 3 cases:

If $x,y \in [-M,M] \Rightarrow f$ is uniformly continuous for some $\delta_1$ (because $[-M,M]$ is compact).

If both $x,y \notin [-M,M]$ then 
$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|f(x)-\ell_2|+|f(y)-\ell_2|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}+\frac{\epsilon}{3} = \frac{2\epsilon}{3} < \epsilon$ for some $\delta_2$

If one of $x,y$ is in $[-M,M]$ and the other is not 
Wlog I assume $x\in[-M,M] \wedge y\notin[-M,M]$ 
then $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq |f(x)-\ell_1|+|\ell_1-f(y)|$, 
and as $x\in[-M,M]$ and f is uniformly continuous on that interval, we can say $|f(x)-\ell_1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$, and as $y\notin[-M,M]$, then $|f(y)-\ell_1|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ 
Therefore, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ for some $\delta_3$


Now taking $\delta:=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}$, we have that 
$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0 / \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}, |x-y|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)|$, which means $f$ is uniformly continuous
I doubt about a lot of points of this demonstration, but I would love if some would remark my errors, so that I can correct them. Thank you very much
Postscript:
I can use as a result that we know that if a continuous function $g$ satisfies that 
$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} g(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty} g(x) = 0$, then it is uniformly continuous, but I didn´t find it useful. If someone wants to try another demonstration assuming that, I would accept it too.

Your general idea is good, but there are a couple points I can see.
I believe your case (2) is incomplete. For $x, y \in \mathbb{R} - [-M, M]$, it could be the case that $x, y < -M$ or $x, y > M$. In each of these cases, the result is pretty much trivial, since for any such $x, y$ we have that
$|f (x) - l|,|f (y) - l|  < \frac{1}{3} \varepsilon \implies |f (y) - f (x)| < \frac{2}{3} \varepsilon < \varepsilon$
where $l = l_1$ in the former case and $l = l_2$ in the latter case.
But there are another two cases, where $x < -M, y > M$ (and vice versa). These pose more of a challenge, because even though $f (x)$ is "close" to $l_2$ and $f (y)$ to $l_1$, if it is the case that $\varepsilon < |l_2 - l_1|$, then we can't necessarily make $f (x)$ and $f (y)$ sufficiently close to each other. However, these cases can be eliminated if you simply select, e.g., $\delta_2 = M > 0$.
Case (3) is also not quite complete. WLOG, we take $x \in [-M, M]$ and $y \in \mathbb{R} - [-M, M]$. But there are two cases for $y$: either $y < -M$ or $y > M$. In the latter case, we can use the continuity of $f$ at the point $x = M$ to guarantee some $\delta_{3, +} > 0$ such that $|x - M| < \delta_{3, +} \implies |f (x) - f (M)| < \frac{1}{6} \varepsilon$. Then, we know that
$$|y - x| < \delta_{3, +} \implies |x - M| < \delta_{3, +} \implies |f (x) - f (M)| < \frac{1}{6} \varepsilon$$
The continuity of $f$ at $x = M$ also guarantees that $|f (M) - l_1| < \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ (which you can check), and from hypothesis, $|f (y) - l_1| < \frac{1}{3} \varepsilon$. These facts together with the triangle inequality imply that $|f (y) - f (x)| < \varepsilon$, as desired. (In a very similar way, in the latter case where $y < -M$, we can find $\delta_{3, -} > 0$ such that $|y - x| < \delta_{3, -} \implies |f (y) - f (x)| < \varepsilon$.)
Now, taking $\delta = \min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2, \delta_{3, +}, \delta_{3, -} \}$, where $\delta_1$ is guaranteed by the uniform continuity of $f$ on the compact interval $[-M, M]$ (considered correctly in case (1)) completes the proof.

Thank you very much
